# How to extend partition for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, disk

I have 128 GB SSD in which 52 GB is allotted to ubuntu and 66 GB is free space. I want to add 66GB space to my ubuntu partition. What is the safest way to do this?
[image]

Comment: I might make sdb1 a bit larger and remove sdb2. The system reserved is required by Windows before the c: "drive" or its install partition. It is not used otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to do it in small steps, and checking if every step works:

1. Create a partition in the empty space.
2. Create a `ext4` file system in the new partition.

You can use Gparted for these steps. Let's say the new partition will be called `/dev/sdb5`.

3. Create a mount point in your home directory: `mkdir ~/mydata`
4. Mount the new partition on the mount point: `sudo mount /dev/sdb5 ~/mydata`

You have now enlarged your home directory by 66 Gb. Use it to store your files. If all of this works, you can consider adding a line to `/etc/fstab` so the partition will be automatically mounted after the next reboot.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but is there a way i can merge these two partitions?

Comment: Certainly, but (1) not from a running system; you would need a Live media, and run Gparted from there; and (2) you would need to first delete the partition you have just made. Also, it is less safe (errors are easily made), so first backup your valuable data.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is:

- backup everything to external drive with say Clonezilla
- try to enlarge current partition with GParted using GParted try-run (you can use GParted live cd for that puprose)
- actually enlarge the partition with GParted - you have "Resize" option in the menu or simply klick and drag left side of the box to the left
- reboot and make fsck that, I think, is included on GParted live media (if not Knoppix includes it for sure)

Reboot and voilà, it works.

Note that having the whole Linux on one partition is ok for home system, but for more serious uses consider lvm and several partitions for different parts of the system like home, var, boot, swap, etc.